# How to run a parameterized query from the PostgreSQL command line

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to run the following parameterized query from the psql command line:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username = :username;
```

How do I set the username parameter on the command line?

I tried this:

```
\set username 'john'
```

But when I run the query, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  column "john" does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE username = john;
                         ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the `psql` documentation, to substitute a `psql` variable into a string as a literal, use `:'variablename'`

This isn't really a parameterised query in the usual sense, as the variable is interpolated into the query string. `psql` knows to escape single quotes, though, so a variable value `');DROP TABLE users;--` will appear literally instead of ending the string and running unwanted SQL.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for clarifying.